# Find processes by command in python

Tags: python, process, psutil

In my Python script, i want to check if `otherscript.py` is currently being run on the (Linux) system. The [psutil](http://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library looked like a good solution:

```py
import psutil
proc_iter = psutil.process_iter(attrs=["name"])
other_script_running = any("otherscript.py" in p.info["name"] for p in proc_iter)
```

The  problem is that `p.info["name"]` only gives the name of the executable of a process, not the full command. So if `python otherscript.py` is executed on the system, `p.info["name"]` will just be `python` for that process, and my script can't detect whether or not `otherscript.py` is the script being run.

Is there a simple way to make this check using psutil or some other library? I realize i could run the `ps` command as a subprocess and look for the `otherscript.py` in the output, but i'd prefer a more elegant solution if one exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wonder if this works

```
import psutil
proc_iter = psutil.process_iter(attrs=["pid", "name", "cmdline"])
other_script_running = any("otherscript.py" in p.info["cmdline"] for p in proc_iter)
```

Answer (score 2):

http://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#find-process-by-name
Take a look at the second example which inspects name(), cmdline() and exe().

For reference:

```
import os
import psutil

def find_procs_by_name(name):
    "Return a list of processes matching 'name'."
    ls = []
    for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=["name", "exe", "cmdline"]):
        if name == p.info['name'] or \
                p.info['exe'] and os.path.basename(p.info['exe']) == name or \
                p.info['cmdline'] and p.info['cmdline'][0] == name:
            ls.append(p)
    return ls
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is checking the process ongoing.
it doesn't matter Linux or Window

```
import psutil

proc_iter = psutil.process_iter()
for i in proc_iter:
    print(i)
```